`git pull` doesn't work from python, but works in the terminal
TLDR: I can run git pull from the terminal and it works, but when I run os.system("/usr/bin/git pull") it doesn't work
I have a uWSGI server working and I'm trying to get a GitHub Webhook to trigger a git pull command to update the code on the server automatically.
I used to use PythonAnywhere, but I'm migrating over to my own Ubuntu server. I've had the auto-update working perfectly on PythonAnywhere, but I just can't get it to work on my own server.
I had and solved several problems to get to where I am (including incorrect working directories, sudo permissions etc.) but this current problem has me stumped.
In python, I run exit_code = os.system("/usr/bin/git pull").
I also have a local post-merge hook that runs sudo systemctl restart myapp.service.
When the auto-update is triggered, I get the following in my uWSGI log:
Git about to pull
error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
Exit code: 256

Some research I did suggested this was a problem to do with ssh keys, but I am able to run git pull myself perfectly fine.
Things I've already tried/fixed:

my SSH key does not have a password
I have set the sudoers.h/updateGit accordingly, so the systemctl restart can be run without a password

Does anyone have any clue what this could be?

Like the error message tells you, it can't find ssh. Probably update the PATH, or pass in GIT_SSH_COMMAND (I think the variable is called) in the environment explicitly.

Related to the comment given by tripleee: Show that part of your git configuration, where you specify the use of ssh.
